# How to restart a keyframe animation with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to find an answer to my problem but I haven't been able to find one.
I want to be able to clear an interval once it's done, but then be able to restart it.
My current code doesn't let me do that: once the interval stops, you can't run it again.
Here's my code:

```js
function about() {
            var about = document.getElementById("about")
            about.classList.add("about-mi")
            var moreinfo = setInterval (function() {
                about.classList.remove("about-mi")
            }, 2000)
            clearInterval(moreinfo)
        }
```

```css
.about-mi {
    animation-name: moreinfo;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes moreinfo {
    0% {color: black;}
    50% {color: red; transform: translateY(-20px);}
    100% {color: black;}
}
```

```html
<a onclick="about()">▼</a>

<h2 id=about>About</h2>
```

I would prefer solutions that only require HTML, CSS, or JavaScript, but I am also open to try solutions that require jQuery.

Comment: That code makes no sense, your interval is cleared immediately, so the callback will never run.

Comment: With your code as written the interval will never run at all. You can always use a non-anonymous defined function as the callback.

Comment: After you've spent some time learning `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, you may want to look into the [animationend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `setInterval` doesn't do anything here. You don't need to use interval for that, just use `setTimeout`.

```js
function about() {
  var about = document.getElementById("about")
  about.classList.add("about-mi")
  var moreinfo = setTimeout(function() {
    about.classList.remove("about-mi")
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
.about-mi {
  animation-name: moreinfo;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes moreinfo {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="about()">▼</a>

<h2 id=about>About</h2>
```

Also you can do this with only CSS

```css
.about-mi {
  animation: moreinfo 2s, reset 2.1s;
}

a:active+.about-mi {
  animation: anything, reset 2.1s;
}

@keyframes moreinfo {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes reset {
  from,
  to {
    color: black;
    transform: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Wait for the animation to finish before first clicking (2.1s). because the animation starts when the page loads.</p>

<a href="#">▼</a>
<h2 id="about" class="about-mi">About</h2>
```

Comment: You will need to cancel the timer when the button is pressed within 2 seconds to prevent odd behavior because of the animation. Try spamming the button like every 1 second.

Comment: @MarkBaijens This specific code seems to only remove a class (not toggling it on and off). So even if the user clicks the button multiple times, the class name basically gets removed multiple times (resulting in the same appearance), or am I missing something?

Comment: @AnisR. The class will be removed before the css animation ended because multiple timers run at once. `animationend` event would resolve that issue as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 2):

As you use the interval timeout to remove the class `about-mi` to match with the `2 seconds` you have defined in your css with `animation-duration: 2s;` it gets hard to mantain when you start changing one of those values you always have to keep in mind ooooh I also have to update the other one say `javascript value` and `css value`

That given, in this case another approach is remove the class based on [HTMLElement: animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event like so:

```js
var aboutElement = document.getElementById("about")

function about() {
    aboutElement.classList.add("about-mi")
}
aboutElement.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
    aboutElement.classList.remove("about-mi");
});
```

```css
.about-mi {
    animation-name: moreinfo;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes moreinfo {
    0% {color: black;}
    50% {color: red; transform: translateY(-20px);}
    100% {color: black;}
}
```

```html
<a onclick="about()">▼</a>

<h2 id=about>About</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, it looks like you only need to run the code once, and not multiple times at intervals, so as @dgknca mentioned, all you need is a `setTimeout`.

---

#### How to restart an interval in general

Answering this in case other users comes across this post. The best you can do (as far as I'm aware) is to define a non-anonymous function with the functionality you want, and then use that in the interval:

```
function doSomething() {
    // your logic here
    console.log('I am doing something.');
}

// execute doSomething every 1 second
var interval = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```

Like so, you can cancel the interval using:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

To "restart" the interval, you would need to assign `interval` to a new interval:

```
interval = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);
```